# Displaying array values through a submit input in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having a problem with displaying array values when I put it through a submit input.

I'm fairly new to PHP coding, and I want to know how to take the value from a checkbox, into a submit input, and finally: displayed to the webpage.

**EDIT - I have updated and included my entire page that I'm working on. To clarify any confusing as to using the two arrays.

```
<?php
//if ($_COOKIE["auth"] == "1") {
  if (filter_input (INPUT_COOKIE, 'auth') == "1") {
    $display_block = "<p>You are an authorized user.</p>";
} else {
    //redirect back to login form if not authorized
    header("Location: userlogin.html");
    exit;
}

$num = range(1,49);//Create a range of numbers from 1-49.

shuffle($num); //Shuffle the numbers
$lotto=array_slice($num,0,6); //Grab 6 random numbers from $num

shuffle($num); //Shuffle & generate 49 numbers.
$lottoMax=array_slice($num,0,7); //Grab 7 random numbers from $num

sort($lotto);
sort($lottoMax);

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lottery Tickets</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" name="Lottery Tickets" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lotto[]" value="lotto"> Lotto 6/49
        <input type="checkbox" name="lottoMax[]" value="lottoMax"> Lotto MAX
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <p>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $lotto=$_POST['lotto'];
                    foreach($lotto as $name){
                        echo $name.'<br/>';
                    }
            }
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $lottoMax=$_POST['lottoMax'];
                    foreach($lotto as $name){
                        echo $name.'<br/>';
                    }
            }
        ?>
    </p>
</body>
```

Any advice/tips/help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: just a question: are you really trying to get both values? seems to me a radio button is much suitable in here

Comment: Unfortunately, our example in the text asks for us to use two checkboxes... "The authorized user can select one or both of the two available lottery services (in form of checkboxes) provided by your website." @Ghost

Comment: oh okay, then i guess checkbox then, check out hanky's answer below

Comment: You want `Lotto 6/49` to be a *value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
$num = range(1,49);//Create a range of numbers from 1-49.

shuffle($num); //Shuffle the numbers
$lotto=array_slice($num,0,6); //Grab 6 random numbers from $num

shuffle($num); //Shuffle & generate 49 numbers.
$lottoMax=array_slice($num,0,7); //Grab 7 random numbers from $num

sort($lotto);
sort($lottoMax);

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lottery Tickets</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" name="Lottery Tickets" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lotto" value=""> Lotto 6/49
        <input type="checkbox" name="lottoMax" value=""> Lotto MAX
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <p>
        <?php

            if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){
              $lottorey1=$_POST['lotto'];
              $lotterey2=$_POST['lottoMax'];

            if(isset($lottorey1)==TRUE)
            {
                $num = range(1,49);//Create a range of numbers from 1-49.

shuffle($num); //Shuffle the numbers
$lotto=array_slice($num,0,6); //Grab 6 random numbers from $num

echo 'Lotto 6/49: ';
foreach ($lotto as $lotto_num)
{
    echo $lotto_num.' ';
}
            }
            echo '<br/>';  
            }
        ?>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: $lotto and $lottoMax are two different arrays.
$lotto has a predefined size of 6, while $lottoMax has 7 and each of these arrays are given a random number from 1-49.

Comment: @Almorrow i try some thing but each time, i got the error, now little bit a search tell me that each check box can only have value, not array of value, can you tell me how many value they got,

Comment: They have values randomly generated through the numbers 1-49.
I just updated my source code and my question. Take a look :) @Alif_suhail_123

Comment: @ALMorrow so what you are trying to do is to hold the array as a value in each checkbox, i dont thing its possible, each individual checkbox can only hold one value, if $lotto and $lottomax are holding one one value each, their is fairly simply solution, but if they are holding an array, Then i am confused, as i dont think check box can hold and array value

Comment: @Almorrow i read one of your last question. on the website, i think these two questions are interconnected, if you can explain to me what you are trying to achieve through check boxes, i might help. Thanks

Comment: As quoted from the example in the text: "the user submits the form with one or both of the two available services checked, your web server will generate six sets of lottery numbers for each type accordingly and display these numbers of each type of lotteries to the user." What I'm trying to figure out right now is simply printing 1 set of lottery tickets, with 2 different arrays. One being Lotto 6/49, and the other being Lotto MAX. The checkboxes act as a choice between what lottery they want, if they select both, they will both be displayed. @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: @ALMorrow see the updated answer, it will generate the lottery number for lotto, but you will get the idea how to do it for other values as well, if you cant do it let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thank you kindly! It works great. Just need to format the output so I can read the numbers easily :-) @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: @ALMorrow how you want me to format the output, tell me, and if it works please accept the answer, i will format for you. Thanks

Comment: I would like it to be... "easier" on the eyes. When I press submit, the array prints properly. But it's all concatenated into one string. For example, this is the output:11836404546. I would like it to look like this: Lotto 6/49: 1, 18, 36, 40, 45, 46. @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: @ALMorrow i did not read you want Lotto 6/49: than the lottery number, read the updated answer it will give you that out put. Thanks, and dont forget to accept the answer if i helped you. Thanks

Comment: @ALMorrow their is one more thing you were doing it wrong, means your logic was wrong, the logic should be in your head is this, you want this code to run if this check box is selected and this to run if this is selected and both to run if both is selected, as checkboxes can only hold one value, Thanks